# What are the conditions over $A(x)$ under which $−\operatorname{div} (A(x)\nabla u_0) = f(x)\ \ \text{in} \ \ \Omega$ is a linear elliptic equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> What are the conditions over $A(x)$ under which
>   $$−\operatorname{div} (A(x)\nabla u_0) = f(x)\ \  \text{in} \ \ \Omega$$
>   is a linear elliptic equations?

This is my answer. Assume that $A = [a_{ij}]$ is a symmetric matrix with $a_{ij} \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, for every $i, j = 1, . . ., N$, and satisfying
$$\lambda |\zeta|^2\leq a_{ij}(x) \zeta_i \zeta_j\leq \Lambda |\zeta|^2$$
for a.e. $x\in\Omega$, $\forall \zeta\in\mathbb R^N$ and for two suitable constants $0 < \lambda \leq \Lambda <\infty$. Assume in addition that $f \in H^{−1} (\Omega)$.

Contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symmetry is not necessary, and the regularity of $f$ is only needed to ensure existence of solutions.